# Select only records with last timestamp of its kind

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores locations of users. I would like to select the latest location of every user.

What I've tried

```
SELECT lat, lng, address, idUser, timestamp FROM locations ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1

SELECT lat, lng, address, idUser, MAX(timestamp) FROM locations
```

Those two, of course, gave me the last location among all users. The structure of the table is simple:

```
CREATE TABLE `locations` (
  `idLocation` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `idUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lat` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `lng` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`idLocation`),
  KEY `idUser` (`idUser`)
)
```

Comment: SELECT lat, lng, address, idUser, timestamp FROM locations ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1

SELECT lat, lng, address, idUser, MAX(timestamp) FROM locations

Those two, of course, gave me the last location among all users. The structure is simple, I didn't include it to keep it short and concise:

CREATE TABLE(
  `idLocations` int(11) auto_increment,
  `idUser` int(11),
  `address` varchar(255),
  `lat` float(10,6),
  `lng` float(10,6),
  `timestamp` timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`idLocations`)
)

Comment: if you tried my answer below, as stated above, and said it gave you the latest location, isn't that what you wanted?? Please clarify what you want otherwise! ;) and please try my entire statement, not just partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in this page, using a self join. Get the latest timestamp for each user and then get the rest of the row by self-joining.

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

```
SELECT
l.idUser,
l.lat,
l.lng,
l.timestamp
FROM (
select idUser, max(timestamp) as maxtimestamp
from locations group by idUsuario)
as max inner join locations as l on l.idUsuario = max.idUsuario and l.timestamp = max.maxtimestamp
GROUP BY idUsuario
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  idUser,
  lat,
  lng,
  MAX(timestamp) AS "MostRecentTime"
FROM table_name
GROUP BY idUser, lat, lng
```

For reference: [Returning Max Values](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Returning_The_Maximum_Value_For_A_Row)

Based on your tablet I'm not really sure why you're adding a number as LocationId. To keep track of the number of times the user's location changes? I'm assuming it's for that purpose-- if it's to find the latest location, it's much easier to just track the most recent timestamp.

Comment: That gave me all the records in the table, since grouping by lat and lng aswell (different values on all records) separated completely the rows.

Comment: And the purpose of the locationID according to my understanding is none. I started to work on this project when the database already existed, and I didn't want to change anything regarding that.